# Стоит ли создать метку UnrealEngine5 или удалить UnrealEngine?

Tags: обсуждение, метки, удаление-метки, создание-метки

Сейчас существует две метки для движка UnrealEngine: [unreal-engine](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unreal-engine) (13 вопросов) и [unreal-engine-4](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unreal-engine-4) (96 вопросов).

В связи с выходом пятой версии движка [UnrealEngine5](https://www.unrealengine.com/en-US/unreal-engine-5), возможно, стоит добавить метку [unreal-engine-5](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unreal-engine-5).

С другой стороны, чтобы не плодить эти метки для каждой версии, лучше, наверно, будет удалить метку [unreal-engine-4](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unreal-engine-4) и перенести все вопросы с ней на [unreal-engine](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unreal-engine), как это уже сделано и успешно используется в метке движка Unity: [unity3d](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d). Она одна и не подразделяется на версии программы, хотя версия Unity тоже уже пятая.

Comment: Я бы создал - вреда от этого никакого.

Comment: @Kromster Я бы тоже создал, а лучше даже удалил, но для этого наверно нужен модератор или кто-то повыше, вот я и создал вопрос.

Comment: Я создал метку для UE5 и повесил ее на пару вопросов